# How to update MudSelect Items on BlazorSever

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Lets say I have two MudSelect controls:

```razor
<MudSelect Class="pa-4" T="string" Label="Market" @bind-Value="Market" TextChanged="MarketChanged">
    @foreach (var market in markets)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@market">@market</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>
<MudSelect @ref="applicationSelector" Class="pa-4" T="string" Label="Application" @bind-Value="Application"/>
```

Now when selecting another market, I want the selectable items in Application Selector to be updated dependent on the selection:

```cs
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> marketApplications { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() {
        { "Market 1", new List<string>() { "Application 1" } },
        { "Market 2", new List<string>() { "Application 2", "Application 3" } }};

private void MarketChanged(string value)
{
    if (applicationSelector is null)
    {
        return;
    }

    applicationSelector.Clear();

    if (marketApplications.ContainsKey(value))
    {
        foreach (string app in marketApplications[value])
        {
            applicationSelector.Items.AddRange(marketApplications[value]); // This doesn't work as Items is readonly
        }
    }
}
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Include more code such as the variable definitions to reproduce on my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using `dictionary` for the applications `MudSelect`, we could use the selected market value as key to this dictionary which will then populate only the application options list for that market.

Additionally you need a callback when the market value is changed, you update the selected market and reset the selected application.

Working code:

```razor
@page "/"

<MudSelect Class="pa-4" T="string" Label="Market" ValueChanged="SelectedValue">
    @foreach (var market in markets)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@market">@market</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

<MudSelect Class="pa-4" T="string" 
           Label="Application" 
           @bind-Value="selectedApplication">
    @foreach (var market in marketApplications[selectedMarket])
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@market">@market</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

@code {
    string selectedMarket = "Market 1";
    string selectedApplication { get;set; }
    
    List<string> markets = new List<string> { "Market 1", "Market 2" };
    
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> marketApplications { get; } = new()
    {
        { "Market 1", new List<string> { "Application 1" } },
        { "Market 2", new List<string> { "Application 2", "Application 3" } }
    };
    
    private void SelectedValue(string selectedValue)
    {
        selectedMarket = selectedValue;
        selectedApplication = string.Empty; // reset
    }
}
```

Online Demo:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wuwcvFOtzhdepIyL

Output:

[image: mudselect updating another mudselect]

Comment: Thanks man, that was so much easier than I thought!