# How to populate MudSelect list at runtime

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I am trying to determine how to populate the items of a MudBlazor MudSelect component in a Server-side app while the app is running. Can someone steer me in the right direction?

I have searched for a solution without success.

Comment: You can check my solution for updating `MudSelect` items at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74377802/8316900. If it does not help, you can provide a minimal code to work on.

Comment: Ibrahim, Shukran! Multsumesc! Dhanyavad! Gracias! Merci! Arigato! Teshekur Ederim! That was exactly what I am trying to accomplish - populate a second list based on the selected value of the first. I exercised the code on mudblazor playground and it did what I want.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear that It was what you were looking for.